Recursion in Python, using window.after()?
Given the following code snippet:
def counting_down(count):
    window.after(1000, counting_down, count - 1)

Since the 2nd line, is not a direct call to counting_down but rather it uses a delay mechanism, is this considered to be a recursion?
So, if count is a very large number, does it mean the calling stack depth might be "exploded" eventually?

Technically, the function works recursively.
Practically, the function does not call itself directly within its execution context. Instead it puts a reference to itself on the event loop stack and completes execution before the next call is made.
In typical recursion all calls to the function are added to the stack "at once" and each function call has to wait for all function calls scheduled after it to complete, before being able to complete itself.
